# Oscilloscopes with open-source software options

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I've been working on a number of electronics projects lately, and while I have a 'scope, it's fairly poor to use (it's one of those pocket ones, and I have complaints about its usability).

Do you know of any PC-connected oscilloscopes that use open-source software? There's the Analog Discovery 2, and the OpenScopeMZ, but those both use either Waveforms (which is closed-source, though free) or Waveforms Online (or whatever) which is allegedly open-source, but that doesn't count since it can't be completely run locally (as far as I know).

WFO supposedly can run offline, but that's only the case as long as I don't close my browser or reboot for a kernel update. If it can be downloaded as a standalong webpage to run offline, that's a different story.

Anyway, please let me know what systems are both good quality and have an application that works offline and is open-source. Thanks!

P.S. Given that I have no tags that directly apply, is this the wrong site to ask this question? I don't know what one it best applies to.

Comment: Possibly [hardwarerecs.se]. State as much as you can about your requirements. Operating system, connectivity, price and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go post it over there.